# parameter Encoder Failed because invalidRootObject?

Tags: json, swift, post, encoding, alamofire

I have problem with parameterEncoderFailed when I try to send JSON string 'parametersString' to web API the error message can someone help me to solve the problem

> failure(Alamofire.AFError.parameterEncoderFailed(reason:
>   Alamofire.AFError.ParameterEncoderFailureReason.encoderFailed(error:
>   Alamofire.URLEncodedFormEncoder.Error.invalidRootObject("string(\"{\n\\"authenticate\\":
>   {\n\\"userName\\": \\"fan.doe\\",\n\\"password\\":
>   \\"12345\\",\n\\"expiry\\": \\"2019-05-03
>   18:00:00\\"\n}\n}\")")))))

```
 static func Login(email:String, password:String, completion: @escaping (_ success: Bool, _ response: DataResponse<Data?>?) -> ()) {
        let urlString: 

        let parametersString = """
        {
        "authenticate": {
        "userName": "\(email)",
        "password": "\(password)",
        "expiry": "2019-05-03 18:00:00"
        }
        }
        """
         var response:DataResponse<Data?>?

        print(urlString)
        AF.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: parametersString, encoding:  String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue,  headers: headers )
            .response { resp in
                response = resp
                print(response)
                if(response?.response?.statusCode == 200){
                    completion(true, response)

                }
                else {
                    completion(false, nil)
                }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to send a dictionary `[String:Any]`

```
let parametersDic:[String:Any] = [
    "authenticate": [
    "userName": "\(email)",
    "password": "\(password)",
    "expiry": "2019-05-03 18:00:00"
]]
```

Comment: That does not fix it

Comment: change `encoding:  String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue`  to  `encoding: JSONEncoding.default`